# Convex function from condition

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Can we deduce that  $F$ is a convex function (i.e $F''(t)>0, \forall t>0$)  from the following conditions:

- $F(t)=\int_{0}^t f(\xi) d\xi$, $0\leq \theta F(t)< t f(t), \forall t>0$
- The function $\frac{f(t)}{t^{p-1}}$ is increasing in $(0,+\infty)$ and satisfy $$\limsup_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(t)}{|t|^s}=0~\text{and}~\lim_{|t|\rightarrow0}\frac{f(t)}{|t|^{p-1}}=0$$
- there exists $\eta\in(p-1,\frac{N(p-1)+p}{N-p})$ and $C>0$ such that $$f'(t)t-(p-1)f(t)\geq C t^{\eta}, ~\forall t>0$$ Where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function, $2\leq p<N$ and $s\in (0,\frac{N(p-1)+p}{N-p}), \theta>p$

Comment: What is $\theta$ ? and do you mean that all conditions need to be satisfied or any of them?

Comment: @MrD $\theta>p$ and i think that one of then gives that $F''(t)>0$ i don't know who ?